# Building cjs and esm using typescript project references in a monorepo

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript monorepo prototype setup and running with cjs, yarn workspaces and project references using incremental builds:

https://github.com/rosskevin/learn-a/tree/build-cjs-esm

Since `tsc -b` uses the default `tsconfig.json` in each project and they are setup for cjs, I'd like to simply pass overrides via command line:

```
yarn tsc -b --outDir lib/esm --module esnext --target esnext                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ✘ 127 
yarn run v1.12.3
$ /Users/kross/projects/js/node_modules/.bin/tsc -b --outDir lib/esm --module esnext --target esnext
error TS5072: Unknown build option '--outDir'.
error TS5072: Unknown build option '--module'.
error TS5072: Unknown build option '--target'.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

What is the best way to get both a cjs and an esm build for a typescript project references project?

Comment: I have the same issue 

Comment: @mkotechno I just pushed an update - it is working now using `tsc` in the child project with overrides (not incremental for esm).  Check the readme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to build for both targets (using incremental where possible) is to execute incrementals for cjs `tsc -b` and non-incremental (it seems) for each of the other projects.

This is currently working:

```
"build": "tsc -b",
"build:esm": "lerna exec --stream --parallel -- ../../node_modules/.bin/tsc --outDir lib/esm --module esnext --target esnext",
```

Here is the prototype repo:

https://github.com/rosskevin/learn-a

Answer (score -3):

At https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

> -b --build
>
> Builds this project and all of its dependencies specified by Project
> References. Note that this flag is not compatible with others on this
> page. See more here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html